# How to resolve broken installation

Tags: linux, kali-linux, desktop-environment, python3

I recently was trying to install a package on my Kali system and in doing so was directed to install python 32 bit. I ran the dpkg command to add i386 arch and confirmed installing `python3:i386`

Almost immediately I was dropped into a tty. I tried an `apt update` and `apt upgrade` and upon not being able to get a desktop I then installed `gdm3` which I thought I had previously used for a DE but it installed as if it were a fresh package.

I can now get a login screen but when I login I'm greeted with a blank screen with my cursor; no icons no gnome sidebar.

Is there some way to resolve this?

Also if it is worth noting, in my tty in the motd/banner it warns that "this is a minimal installation of kali".

Is this normal?

TLDR;
How do I install packages that a prior package installation removed in an efficient way

Answer (score 0):

Must've missed this: `apt install kali-desktop-gnome` got me my desktop back.

I'm guessing I'm going to have a bunch of broken packages still but at least I have a desktop. :/

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1081938/